# How to set Android ListView's cell height as half of cell width?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use constraint layout as below. But the aspect ratio is not respected in the actual layout. Instead, the height is actually wrapping the content inside

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"

    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"> 

        <!-- some content inside -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I then think it might be because I didn't set `width="0dp"` (let constraint decide the width). So I tried another way like below. But then the width becomes zero.

**What is the correct way of doing it?**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"

    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"> 

        <!-- some content inside -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**EDIT**: working solution after inspired by Anddenver 's answer (with modification):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1">



    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**Further Edit:**

It seems I need to wrap one more layer of constraint layout for my inner contents .... :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <actual contents here..../>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>




    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or, just remove the `FrameLayout`, and wrap `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1">

contents here...

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: your start and end are the same, `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"` should be `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`

Comment: maybe `layout_constraintWidth_percent`?

Comment: @IgnacioTomasCrespo corrected now. Still not giving the right width/height ratio.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I read the doc about `layout_constraintWidth_percent`, seems it constrains the `width` to percentage of parent's `width`? But I need the height to be fixed ratio with width, it is a different use case.

Comment: @modeller it adjusts the one dimension with `0dp` set... even if it says "width".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need inner view for that, for example:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<FrameLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1">

    <YOUR CONTENT>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: dimensionRatio screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView), you'd need to inflate a custom `list_item.xml`

and this should be `H,2:1`, to constrain the height to a `2:1` aspect ratio.

The default `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is just a `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1"
    ...
    />
```

see [DimensionConstraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints).